# PHP in <img/> not working on Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, image, permalinks, buddypress

I'm trying to build a custom Wordpress template but I'm struggling with some PHP... 
So, basically, I just want to show the avatar of the Buddypress users.
It works when I write:

```
a href="<?php bp_member_permalink(); ?>"><?php bp_member_avatar('type=full&width=180&height=180'); ?></a>
```

But that means the image doesn't have a class or anything... So I'd like to include it in an `<img/>`. 
But it doesn't work when I do:

```
a href="<?php bp_member_permalink(); ?>"><img src="<?php bp_member_avatar('type=full&width=180&height=180'); ?>" alt=""/></a>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you had a look into the function `bp_member_avatar`?

Comment: What does it do?  Is there an error?  Is the src blank?  Give more info if you want an answer

Comment: What does `bp_member_avatar('type=full&width=180&height=180');` return?

Comment: Looks like it'd echo an `<img>` tag, considering the code that works.  Maybe there's some way to set attributes.

Comment: Apparently the function prints the whole <img> tag already, so you have to look into the function and alter it there - or find a function which just returns the image URL

Comment: @cHao Yeah, I think that's the problem... I haven't found a function that doesn't return an <img> tag... That sucks...

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, BuddyPress sets a class of `avatar` on avatars by default.  You ought to be able to use that.

I'm looking at some BuddyPress code, though, and...well...you know that string you're passing?  You can pass a `class` attribute the same as you do the others, if the default doesn't suit you.  The code that generates the tag appears to recognize `id`, `class`, `alt`, `width`, `height`, and `type`.

```
<a href="<?php bp_member_permalink(); ?>"><?php
   bp_member_avatar('type=full&width=180&height=180&alt=blah&class=whatever');
?></a>
```

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: Sorry. I was a bit quick to assume that you didnt echo it out. Apparently your php function is allready echoing out the html.

First of all, I would replace the html code in your post, because it looks messy and it's not very readable. But that's upto you.

I would code it like this if I absolutely had to mix html and php:

```
<? echo '<a href="' . bp_member_permalink() . '">' . bp_member_avatar("type=full&width=180&height=180") . '</a>'; ?>
```

Second, you have to find the bp_member_avatar() function, and edit the html directly there. Alternatively. If you just need a class, to style this img, this could be done with css and a small alteration to the code:

```
<? echo '<p class="bp_member_avatar"><a href="' .  bp_member_permalink() . '">' . bp_member_avatar("type=full&width=180&height=180") . '</a></p>'; ?>
```

And then use this css to access the image:

```
p.bp_member_avatar a img {
         border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Comment: `bp_member_avatar` doesn't return the image tag; it echoes it into the page.  And your final snippet is just all kinds of confused; i'm fairly certain PHP will choke on it due to the mixed-up quotes.

Comment: If you insist on echoing avatars, then use `bp_get_member_avatar` instead.  It returns the image tag rather than spitting it out into the page (which seems near certain to result in the avatar image being outside the link, as the string will be evaluated -- causing the image tag to be output -- before it's echoed).

Comment: It's very hard to know what to use and what not to use, as I haven't seen the functions for this wordpress plugin/custom class/function or whatever it is. I'm trying to give a proper answer based on the information given by the person who asked the question. php functions or classes echoing out html is generally just bad practice and something I tought peoples in their right mind wouldnt do.

I see you have researched this spesific function and can give the asker a better answer then I could do from a general perspective without seeing the actual code.

Comment: For reference: http://phpxref.ftwr.co.uk/buddypress/nav.html?index.html is a web the BuddyPress stuff.  http://phpxref.ftwr.co.uk/buddypress/nav.html?bp-members/bp-members-template.php.html is where the functions in question are defined.